# eclipse not showing javascript syntax errors

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Eclipse Luna isn't showing javascript syntax errors as I type. The red marks won't show up.

I've searched the web a lot, but couldn't find a solution. Can someone hep, please?

The red flags I'm talking about are the ones showed in the example bellow. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are actually using the Javascript editor? Right click on the file on Porject Explorer and look at the 'Open With...' menu to see what you are using.

Comment: hi, yes, it is the javascript editor.